# Network maintenence time - Cisco & Juniper

Tags: cisco, juniper

I maintain Cisco & Juniper equipment, lately developers are complaining that router upgrades take too long. Since we don't have high availability yet.
How would I cut downtime?

I currently do:

```
(Juniper)
root> request system software add ftp://10.10.70.2/jinstall-ex-2200-12.3R9.4-domestic-signed.tgz 

[Sep 19 21:49:31]: Checking pending install on fpc0
Fetching package...


(Cisco)
2911#copy ftp://admin:123456@10.10.10.3/c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.154-3.M2.bin flash
Destination filename [c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.154-3.M2.bin]? 
Accessing ftp://*****:*****@10.10.10.3/c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.154-3.M2.bin...!
```

Comment: Schedule and announce the downtime in advance. If devs have a problem with it, tell them to advocate up the chain for more money to purchase a failover router.

Comment: How long does it take?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Juniper,

```
root> request system software add no-copy no-validate ftp://10.10.70.2/jinstall-ex-2200-12.3R9.4-domestic-signed.tgz
```

add `no-copy` and `no-validate` to cut validation time

For Cisco,

```
Router#copy ? 
/erase Erase destination file system. 
/error Allow to copy error file. 
/noverify Don't verify image signature before reload.
```

Enable `/noverify`

Comment: -1, this does absolutely nothing to reduce downtime and does a great job of potentially increasing it.  Adding in `no-validate` basically turns off `commit check` for the new version - the action that ensures the configuration will run when booted.  Adding `/noverify` turns off the integrity checking of the new image (to see if it was a good copy).  Disabling either risks the systems from not booting the way you are expecting (if at all).